# wp-admin edit user url wont show up correct url

Tags: wp-admin, users, urls

was expecting the **edit** url (shot below) would point me to something like:

website.co/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=7&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php <-- expected url

Instead of

website.co/my-account/edit-account/&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fusers.php <-- ended up here

Also, I've read through some forums it might conflict with woocommerce or other plugins but tried to disabling all those plugins and still gave me the wrong link. Did I missing something? thanks

[image]

Comment: you mentioned disabling certain plugins. Have you disabled ALL plugins and switched your theme to something else, like 2020, and then tested this?  SOMETHING is changing this. You just haven't found it. Why not try disabling everything and re-enable 1 at a time until you find it?

Comment: It looks like it's attempting to direct the user to the WooCommerce My Account page rather than the back end user edit screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paul G. you're right, switched to another theme showed the right link for editing user.

My bad though, I missed `functions.php` from child theme where its modified `add_filter('get_edit_user_link', ...`